# Setting only one Countdown timer to work in iterated loop when clicked

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter application with iterations,and in each iteration there is a countdown button.

When I click on the button the countdown of all the iterations work however my objective is to make only one countdown work.

Here is the countdown function:

```
  int _countdownTime = 45;
  late Timer _countdownTimer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 0), () {});

  void startCountdownTimer() {
    const oneSec = const Duration(seconds: 1);
    _countdownTimer = new Timer.periodic(
      oneSec,
      (Timer timer) => setState(
        () {
          if (_countdownTime < 1) {
            timer.cancel();
            _countdownTime = 45; // Reset countdown timer to 45 seconds
          } else {
            _countdownTime = _countdownTime - 1;
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void _handleCountdownTap() {
    if (_countdownTimer == null || !_countdownTimer.isActive) {
      startCountdownTimer();
    }
  }
```

here is the UI:

```
for (var breakdown in snapshot.data![index].breakdowns)
  Card(
    margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0, right: 8.0),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Text(
              '${breakdown.order}',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: _handleCountdownTap,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    '$_countdownTime seconds',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

My question how to get only one countdown timer to work when clicked instead of all the iterations in the breakdown. Is there another solution or approach to fix this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My App',
      home: CountdownExample(),
    );
  }
}

class CountdownExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CountdownExampleState createState() => _CountdownExampleState();
}

class _CountdownExampleState extends State<CountdownExample> {
  List<int> _countdownTimes = List.filled(3, 45);
  final List<Timer?> _countdownTimers = List.filled(3, null);

  void startCountdownTimer(int index) {
    const oneSec = const Duration(seconds: 1);
    _countdownTimers[index] = new Timer.periodic(
      oneSec,
      (Timer timer) => setState(
        () {
          if (_countdownTimes[index] < 1) {
            timer.cancel();
            _countdownTimes[index] = 45; // Reset countdown timer to 45 seconds
          } else {
            _countdownTimes[index] = _countdownTimes[index] - 1;
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void _handleCountdownTap(int index) {
    if (_countdownTimers[index] == null || !_countdownTimers[index]!.isActive) {
      startCountdownTimer(index);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Countdown Example'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 3,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Card(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Text(
                      'Breakdown ${index + 1}',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => _handleCountdownTap(index),
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            '${_countdownTimes[index]} seconds',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can create a widget which has timer logic on each item. Something like

```dart
for (var breakdown in snapshot.data![index].breakdowns) {
  BreakdownCard(
    key: ValueKey(breakdown.order),
    label: breakdown.order);
}

class BreakdownCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final String label;
  const BreakdownCard({super.key, required this.label});

  @override
  State<BreakdownCard> createState() => _BreakdownCardState();
}

class _BreakdownCardState extends State<BreakdownCard> {
  int _countdownTime = 45;
  Timer _countdownTimer = Timer(const Duration(seconds: 0), () {});

  void startCountdownTimer() {
    const oneSec = Duration(seconds: 1);
    _countdownTimer = Timer.periodic(
      oneSec,
      (Timer timer) => setState(
        () {
          if (_countdownTime < 1) {
            timer.cancel();
            _countdownTime = 45; // Reset countdown timer to 45 seconds
          } else {
            _countdownTime = _countdownTime - 1;
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void _handleCountdownTap() {
    if (!_countdownTimer.isActive) {
      startCountdownTimer();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0, right: 8.0),
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Text(
                widget.label,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 30,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: _handleCountdownTap,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      '$_countdownTime seconds',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```